# mySQL: count data field that is "new" for 7 days

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do some count to "new" uploaded files, taking the date into consideration. What I want to do is:

```
date1: 2018-02-08 -> will add to count value until 2018-02-15 is reached.
date2: 2018-02-01 -> will add to count value until 2018-02-08 is reached. 
date3: 2018-01-20 -> will add to count value until 2018-01-27 is reached.
```

In the example above, the result should be (2), because date3 is already passed the 7 days.

I've tried the following query without success:

```
"SELECT count(idFicheiro) from ficheiros where DATE(date) < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option
(assuming date is already a date field)

```
SELECT count(idFicheiro) from ficheiros where DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 7
```